# NO puedo enviar archivo en un FormData usando Angular 8

Tags: angular, archivo, post, angular8

Tengo este código

```
onUpload() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('photo', this.mainPhoto, this.mainPhoto.name);
    this.eventServ.uploadPhoto(fd).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log('Archivo subido: ', res);
      }
    );
  }
```

Pero me está sucediendo algo que no entiendo. El FormData se envía vacío. Ahí lo que debe ir es un archivo que capturo en otro método y lo asigno a la propiedad mainPhoto y cuando compruebo todo es correcto. Pero no sé que está pasando que se envía vacío al servicio. Puse un *console.log()* antes y despues del método .append() y no hay cambio en la variable. 
Pasa lo mismo si le añado otro parámetro que sea texto.
Si aguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería. Estoy usando Angular 8

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con que no hay cambio en la variable?

Comment: ¿Como declaraste `mainPhoto`?

Comment: Como estas cargando la foto?  `uploadPotho` tiene que llevar una lógica para poder realizar la carga. Lo puedes publicar?

Comment: Deberías tener un método dónde asignas el valor del input file a mainPhoto. Puedes compartirlo??

Comment: Me han dicho que a otros les han pasado. Esto pareciera ser un bug de Angular, y aunque vi un tutorial que mandaban el archivo sin problema, pero en mi caso resolví haciendo oo que ven abajo.

Comment: Para capturar la foto utilizo el evento change en el input y ahí voy a target.files[] donde puedo capturar el archivo enviado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré mandar el archivo haciendo lo siguiente:

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('photo', this.mainPhoto, this.mainPhoto.name);
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:1337/media/upload');
request.send(fd);
```

Pero cuando llamo al servicio que envía las peticiones, no se me ejecuta, pero solamente y específicamente para este caso donde envío un archivo.

```
//create-event.ts
this.eventServ.uploadPhoto(fd).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log('Archivo subido: ', res);
      }
    );
// event.service.ts
public uploadPhoto(data: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log(data);
    return this.http.post(
      environment.apiUrl + 'media/upload/', data,
      // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      { headers: environment.headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;') });
  }
```

Comment: Amigo, puedes decirme exactamente como lo hiciste. Llevo 1 mes intentando y nada que puedo enviar imagenes a mi servidor. Por favor ayudame

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que establecer en el header en 'enctype' en lugar del 'Content-Type':

```js
public uploadPhoto(data: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log(data);
    return this.http.post(
      environment.apiUrl + 'media/upload/', data, 
      // Aca es donde debes cambiar a 'enctype'
      { headers: environment.headers.set('enctype', 'multipart/form-data;') });
  }
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.